# How to reposition the resize indicator in a textarea

Tags: html, css, user-controls, textarea

I'd like to make a textarea float to the right, but that would show the `resize:both;` style that's default to textareas on the right side, while the resizing itself would expand the textarea to the left.

The HTML I'm using is simply:

```
<textarea style="float:right;"></textarea>
```

but it is much clearer to see what I mean by [viewing this demo](http://jsbin.com/pobo/2/). As you can see, resizing the textarea will require you to drag to the right, while it will expand to the left. Is there a way for me to reposition the little indicator in the corner of the textarea to the left side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, that is not a feature that is exposed by the browsers at this time. It's a relatively new feature to HTML, as it is, and I don't think there are any semantic or programmatic hooks to that UI piece of textareas yet.

Your best bet, at this point then will be to fake it with drag-and-drop JS and pseudo-controls, and hide the native resize.

Actually, I stand (somewhat) corrected. According to a comment in this article (http://davidwalsh.name/textarea-resize), you can play around with the resize widget, but only in Safari at the time of that comment:

> Greg March 11, 2013
>
> In webkit you can play around with the scrollbar styling.
>   I used >
>      ::-webkit-resizer{background-color:transparent;}
>      ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}
>
> to style the resizer on the textareas in one of my sites.

(Easier to read in the comments section there.)

Comment: More details on the features available are at http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/ ... it appears that some of these items may work in Chrome as well, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I didn't see your edits until quite late, I'm sorry. This seems like it's going to exist, but just not yet. I guess I'll have to accept that then, I guess. Thanks!